# Encryption and Decryption in Java using AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes

How to `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` in Java using AES

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class Encryption {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
                String t = "Testing";

                byte[] dataToSend = t.getBytes();
                byte[] key = new byte[16];

                Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
                c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
                byte[] encryptedData = c.doFinal(dataToSend);
                System.out.println(encryptedData);

                byte[] key2 = new byte[16];
                        byte[] encryptedData2 = encryptedData;

                        Cipher c2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                        SecretKeySpec k2 =
                          new SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES");
                        c2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k2);
                        byte[] data = c.doFinal(encryptedData);
                        System.out.println(data);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you post all that code? Does it have a problem? If so, are we supposed to guess it? Why not telling us instead?

Comment: 128 bit is already weak, try 1024.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem is not specified explicitly, I am pointing out the obvious errors with the presumption that 'Testing' encrypted should print 'Testing' once decrypted.

1. `AES` is a [symmetric key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) algorithm, hence you have to use the same key for encrypting and decrypting (`k2` should not be there at all)
2. `c.doFinal` of the encrypted data doesn't make much sense, this should be reference to your Cipher `DECRYPT_MODE` -> `c2`

Hence, change:

```
c2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k2);
```

To:

```
c2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
```

And change:

```
byte[] data = c.doFinal(encryptedData);
```

To:

```
byte[] data = c2.doFinal(encryptedData);
```

To print the final outcome:

Change:

```
System.out.println(data);
```

To:

```
System.out.println(new String(data));
```